# JTable clicked row listener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, listener

I have a dynamic `JTable` that contains a string matrix, and I need to write a listener that when double click on a row, read a specific column and make some computation on it. Which kind of listener should I use?

Answer (score 5):

Implement the `MouseListener` or extend the `MouseAdapter`. You can try something like this:

```
yourJTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evnt) {
        if (evnt.getClickCount() == 1) {
            getPropertyFromRow((String)(t_property.getValueAt(yourJTable.getSelectedRow(),0)));
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: i've use the implementation of another user, but seems that he calcel his answer (i've associated also isConsumed() method for catch double click). 
But why getClickCount == 1 ? how listener count click? i've occours that if getClickCount == 2, listener is waked up after three click on row!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [getClickCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29) of `MouseEvent` method after implementing the `MouseListener` or extending the `MouseAdapter` . Sample :

```
yourJTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     if (e.getClickCount() == 2) { // check if a double click
       // your code here
     }
   }
});
```